# Debugger for sublime

Tags: javascript, debugging, editor

Sublime is fastest and user friendly editor tool , I'm Front end develop work on  html , css , js  coding . Is X debug is only tool available for sublime or any thing more good  is available , Please suggest me good debugger tool or plugin for sublime .looking for good suggestions

Comment: What language are you trying to debug? JS?

Comment: Although I want to see this answered... I'm pretty sure this is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: yes , suggest me plugin or debugger for sublime for js file